Uploading to LCS Dynamics using API
Trying to upload a file to the LCS Dynamics using API but keep getting failed due to permission errors.
I'm currently working on a project in LCS Dynamics 365, and Microsoft has made changes to the workflow of LCS, introducing multiple geolocations for creating and accessing projects. My project is heavily integrated with Azure DevOps, and I have to manually download the package from the build pipeline and add it to the shared asset library each time. Some of these files are quite large, and it can take up to 5-6 hours to upload them to the environment. Additionally, certain packages must be added to the asset library in multiple environments. I'm wondering if there's a way to use the LCS Dynamics API service to upload the file to single or multiple environments at once.
After referring to the Microsoft LCS API documentation, I came across a PowerShell script called Invoke-D365LcsUpload.ps1, which includes a function for uploading the file to the environment. However, despite attempting to execute the script multiple times, I encountered a permission error ("you don't have access to start/upload to the environment"). I've also tried using accounts with higher levels of privilege (project owner/environment manager), but I'm still facing the same error.
I'm exploring whether it's possible to:

Directly upload to the LCS environment via Azure DevOps pipeline.
Utilize the LCS Dynamics API to upload the packages.

or any other secure methods to accomplish the task

Did you manually try the PowerShell script Invoke-D365LcsUpload.ps1 to upload the files from your local machine? Does it work when locally? If it also cannot work, the problem should be on the PowerShell script itself, and you need to check the cmdlet in the script. You first need to ensure the PowerShell script can work locally. If it does not work locally, it is not possible to guarantee it the script can work in pipeline.

Instead of calling the LCS related API in PowerShell script, you can try to use the extension "Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations Tools" in Azure DevOps.

I did run it locally, but the script was from Microsoft. so I don't think the error is in the script.

Try the script to make sure it can work as expected. Even if the script is from Microsoft, you still need to check if the there is any thing need to be adjust in the script according to your actual projects. As mentioned above, If the script cannot work locally, it is not possible to guarantee the script can work in pipeline. @Siddarth

Instead of calling the LCS related API in PowerShell script, you can try to use the Azure DevOps extension "Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations Tools" Published by Microsoft. It provides the pipeline task "Dynamics Lifecycle Services (LCS) Asset Upload" (LCSAssetUpload@2) to upload assets to the LCS asset library.
Note: The LCSAssetUpload task is available for classic release pipelines and YAML pipelines, and not for classic build pipelines.
To use the LCSAssetUpload task in your pipeline, you can do like as below:

Install the "Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations Tools" extension to your Azure DevOps organization/collection.


Create a Dynamics Lifecycle Services service connection (LCS Connection). Provide the required information on the service connection. You just need to provide the valid Username (e-mail address) and Password, and a customized Service connection name. Ensure the Username and Password have the access to the target LCS asset library.


In the pipeline, you can configure with the following steps in the same job.

The build step to generate the asset files and output the files to a specified directory.
Use the ArchiveFiles@2 task to archive the asset files as a ZIP from the build output directory, and save ZIP file to another path.
Use the LCSAssetUpload task to the ZIP file to LCS asset library.

variables:
  LCS_Connection: 'myLCS'
  LCS_ProjectId: 'xxxxxx'
  LCS_AssetName: 'xxxx'

steps:
- the build step to generate the asset files 

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive Files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'path/to/build/output/dir'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: LCSAssetUpload@2
  displayName: 'LCS Asset Upload'
  name: UploadAsset
  inputs:
    serviceConnectionName: '$(LCS_Connection)'
    projectId: '$(LCS_ProjectId)'
    assetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    assetName: '$(LCS_AssetName)'

- script: echo "AssetId = $(UploadAsset.FileAssetId)"
  displayName: 'Verify Asset ID'



In addition, once the LCSAssetUpload task run successfully, it will generate an output variable (FileAssetId) to return the file asset ID of the uploaded asset. On the subsequent steps within the same job, if you wants to use the asset ID, you can reference the output variable using the expression $(UploadAsset.FileAssetId).  The 'UploadAsset' is the customized name on the LCSAssetUpload task.

EDIT:
There is no method to bypassed MFA when the account used on the LCS Connection has MFA set.
As recommended in the documentation "Create a Lifecycle Services (LCS) connection in Azure Pipelines", you can try to set up a separate user account that does not have MFA set. For security purposes, you can set this account to have limited access and strong credentials that can regularly be rotated.



This has been super helpful, thanks for the answer. But the catch is, I am only able to upload to the asset library when my account doesn't have multi-factor authentication. When an account with MFA is used, it shows an error: 'Error creating new file asset: 'Invalid OAuth token was presented. Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access 'xxxxxxxxxx'. "Can this be bypassed somehow?

@Siddarth, The MFA cannot be bypassed. The recommended method is setting up a separate user account that does not have MFA set. See EDIT in my answer above.

yeah, Sure thing :)
